# String-byte conversion and concatenation in C#

Tags: c#, vb6, hex, byte, concatenation

I'd like to ask for the equivalents of the following VB6 code in C#
As you can see here, I'm trying to make a basic encryption code which converts each letter to bytes and then again convert to Hexadecimal...

```
Public Function Encrypt(s As String) As String
    Dim bytArray() As Byte
    bytArray = StrConv(s, vbFromUnicode)
    For i = LBound(bytArray) To UBound(bytArray)
        Encrypt = Encrypt & Hex(bytArray(i))
    Next i
End Function
```

I've tried a little bit of C# but I can't figure it out...

```
private string encrypt(string s, byte[] bytArray, string t)
{
    bytArray = ????;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length ????; i++{
        t += Hex(bytArray[i]); ????
    }
    return t;
}
```

I'm sorry I am really a novice in C# and I've gotten so adapted in BASIC that I don't know how to get used in other languages... please help... thanks!

Comment: Why are you passing in `bytArray` and `t`?  Maybe you should start by reading some basic C# tutorials to just learn the language.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to encrypt the string i think you'd better use XOR (^ in C#) than &.
Here is the example of something like you've wrote:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "test input";
        byte[] key = new byte[input.Length];
        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
        {
            key[i] = (byte)r.Next();
        }
        var result = Encrypt(input, key);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static string Encrypt(string inp, byte[] key){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < inp.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(inp[i] & key[i]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

you will not be able to decode the string using &

C# has System.Security.Cryptography namespace with encryption algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Define "encrypt". Do you really just mean "obfuscate"? Are you trying to replicate the original VB6 *exactly*? Or simply achieve a similar effect?

One possible approach (this will encode to Unicode bytes):

```
using System.Text;

string Encrypt(string text)
{
    return string.Concat(
        Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
}
```

Another possibility (this will be exactly the same result as the VB6 code):

```
using System.Text;

string Encrypt(string text)
{
    return string.Concat(
        Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
}
```

The only difference between the two is which text encoding is used to convert to bytes.

Comment: Error: The type of argumens for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select .... blah .... Try specifying the type arguments explicitly....

Comment: Works fine for me as-is. You may have copied the code incorrectly. Or maybe you're targeting an older version of .NET? Note that you also need `using System;` and `using System.Linq;`, but I don't think if you'd left those out, you would have gotten an error message like the one you've partially quoted. Posting the _complete_ error text might give me or someone else a better idea of what's going wrong on your end.

Comment: Probably, yes, I copied the code incorrectly... Am using the phone, afterall...

Anyways, am using VS2013 and .NETfx 4.5 here... and all those namespace you mentioned are here...

lemme ask: what goes after b.ToString? and I don't understand where b came from cause I haven't seen it defined.   Hehe

Comment: `b` is defined in the lambda expression `b => b.ToString("x")`. The declaration of `b` is the very first character in that expression.

Comment: I don't understand the question "what goes after `b.ToString`?" Literally, the characters you see in my post: `("x2")));` are what go after `b.ToString`. But it seems like that'd be obvious, so maybe you mean something else?

Comment: Yes! literally, i was meaning that... Sorry for giving inc. details... it works now, somehow... just that, u said "x2" but "a" produces "6100"... 
but if I exclude '2', it becomes "610"... and one more thing... If i remove "select(b..........", it produces "970"... why are there extra 0s?

thanks, anyways... if possible, i'll try to figure that out, myself... i'm using 2 textboxes, btw

Comment: There are extra 0's because the conversion is using Unicode encoding and the most common letters only have the lower byte set. The "2" in the format specifier tells the formatter how many digits to provide. This ensures each byte always gets two digits, even if the leading digits are 0. (After more research, I see that I didn't do exactly the same conversion your code does...I thought it was converting _to_ Unicode bytes, but apparently it's converting _from_ Unicode to the current system code page. I'll update my answer to clarify)

Answer (score 0):

**exact version**

VB.NET

```
Public Function Encrypt(s As String) As String
    Encrypt = String.Empty
    Dim byteArray() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s)
    For Each b As Byte In byteArray
        Encrypt &= Hex(b)
    Next
End Function
```

C#

```
static string Encrypt(string s)
{
    string encrypt = "";
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
    foreach (byte b in byteArray)
    {
        encrypt += String.Format("{0:x}", System.Convert.ToInt64(b));
    }
    return encrypt;
}
```

**short version - requires string formatting**

VB.NET

```
Public Function Encrypt(s As String) As String
    Dim byteArray() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s)
    Encrypt = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray)
End Function
```

C#

```
static string Encrypt(string s)
{
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
    string encrypt = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray);
    return encrypt;
}
```